# how to diff and show only exact differences for 2 long string

Tags: sql, unix, informix, 4gl

I have 2 files- a and b.

## a

```
1,"abc","( @docid =""00123"" or @docid =""00456"") AND a_number is not NULL"
```

## b

```
1,"abc","( @docid =""00123"" or @docid =""00456"") AND @a_number is not NULL"
```

How do I diff this 2 files and show only the part changes in a_number instead of the whole string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use

```
$ wdiff a b

# 1,"abc","( @docid =""00123"" or @docid =""00456"") AND [-a_number-] {+@a_number+} is not NULL"
```

Comment: isit possible to use "diff" as the command?

Comment: I don't think so, or I've never found the option to make him do it :-)